# How do I find the first variable such that every variable variable afterwards has the same value?

Tags: loops, sas

I have data where the variables are systematically named fr(yyyy) and there is only 1 observation. I think of it as a function fr(yyyy) = x. At some point this function becomes constant, and I want to let a macro variable equal the first year the function is constant. The data goes from fr2016 until fr2078. Here is an example of what it looks like;

[image: source data example]

The correct answer for this data is short_end = 2021.

Here is my attempt;

```
%let fundyr = 2017;
%let endyr = 2078;

data test;
    set disc_rates;
ARRAY  fr{%eval(&fundyr.-1):&endyr.} fr%eval(&fundyr.-1)-fr&endyr.; 
do i = &fundyr. to &endyr.;
    if fr(i) ne fr(i-1) then do j = i to (&endyr.-i);
        if and(fr(i) = fr(j)) then short_end = i; 
        end;
    end;
run;
```

I think logically it makes sense (but it probably is quite right just yet), however there is no and() function that will 'and' together any number of logical statements at once. Any suggestions on how to overcome this, or approach it differently? Also, how can I make this variable a macro variable once it's found?

If you need some data use this to create some

```
data disc_rates;
fr2017 = 0.1;
fr2018 = 0.2;
fr2019 = 0.3;
fr2020 = 0.4;
fr2021 = 0.3;
fr2022 = 0.3;
fr2023 = 0.3;
fr2024 = 0.3;
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over the array *backwards*.

```
data disc_rates;
fr2017 = 0.1;
fr2018 = 0.2;
fr2019 = 0.3;
fr2020 = 0.4;
fr2021 = 0.3;
fr2022 = 0.3;
fr2023 = 0.3;
fr2024 = 0.3;
run;

data want;
  set disc_rates;
  array fr[*] fr2017-fr2024;
  final_rate = fr[dim(fr)];
  do _i = dim(fr) to 1 by -1;
    if fr[_i] ne final_rate then leave;
  end;
  final_rate_index = _i+1;  *_i will be highest non-identical; _i+1=lowest identical;
   Final_rate_year = vname(fr[final_rate_index]);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply, this returns the column number, not the year though, any chance you can adjust it? I've tried but I get an "out of range error"

Comment: You can use VNAME() to get the variable name as text.

Comment: Another method to get the 'year' is to index your array with the years.  `array fr[2017:2024] fr2017-fr2024;`